# Create task based on category & subcategory

Tags: workflow

Based on the case record type in the case record two fields are there name Category/Sub-Category 1 based on the field selections the task should be created.

I have  to create task created for any Talent (Relation – Employee cases)- record type  that has the following Category/Sub-Category 1 options selected moving forward:

```
Category: Talent Relations: Consultation, Sub-Category 1: A
Category: Talent Relations: Consultation, Sub-Category 1: LF
Category: Talent Relations: Inquiry, Sub-Category 1: A
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please understand that "ASAP" and "urgent" requests are  considered inappropriate - this is a community, not a coding service. What have you tried to accomplish this objective? What formula have you written so far? Taking a look at [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) can help understand what we need from you in a question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this pretty easily using standard workflow rules, or process builder.  (I'm a fan of process builder, but you could go with either.)

Set up your entry criteria so that records are ONLY evaluated on create.  If the record meets the criteria you described, then create the appropriate task records.

Take a look:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: Priyamishara, were you able to get this working?